# Create View that references view not created yet

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, schema

I have a schema extraction tool for SQL & Oracle which then tries to create a new database from the schema of another one.

I have encountered a problem with SQL at the moment (most likely exists in Oracle) that when it tries to do something like

```
CREATE VIEW TestView
SELECT * FROM AnotherViewNotCreated
```

it errors.

I thought using the `EXEC` command in SQL would work but it also complains that the view does not exist.

Is there a way I can create the views even if they reference other views that do not exist yet?

**UPDATE:** I've noticed if you Generate Scripts from SQL it outputs the order of view creation in an order that seems to suggest it knows which ones should be created first to prevent reference issues.  Wonder how it knows?

Comment: It knows precisely because it doesn't allow views to be created without resolvable dependencies.

Comment: I don't think this will help in your case, but SQL Server does have a `CREATE SCHEMA` statement block that allows you to declare dependent objects (even mutually dependent ones) in an arbitrary order.  This makes it much easier to declare certain schemas — although it still requires you to declare all of the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could you create the view if it calls a view that doesn't exist yet? You simply have to run scripts in dependency order.

I would not recommend using views that call other views for performance reasons. We nearly lost a multi-million dollar client because some application developer thought this was a good idea. It worked fine until there were large amounts of data and then the sytem slowed to a crawl. Views that call other views, espcially when they go more than one level down, can be particularly diffiult to troubleshoot and maintain. I would really think about whether this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  [This thread](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1657085-sql-server-how-do-i-ignore-errors-view-creation.html) suggests you "fake" the table first, which may work for you, but you may need to re-create the dependent view when the real one is available.